# SQL Query Help: Fetch all rows with same first name and with a last names matching a defined list

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, records

Table Design:

```
First_Name Last_name
```

There are several records which have same first name but different last name. I need to find all the records which have same first name and a defined list of last name.

For example:

```
First_Name Last_name
John       Pohn
John       Qohn
John       Rohn
Jack       Rohn
Jack       Pohn
Sam        Pohn
Sam        Rohn
Sam        Qohn
```

Last name list: Pohn and Qohn

Thus my query should only pick these records

```
John Pohn
John Qohn
Sam  Pohn
Sam Qohn
```

Comment: @Justin your edit totally changed the question... I don't think that this is what Curious meant, I think that he wanted to find all the "John"s with last name *ohn

Comment: @alfasin - what do you mean? Justin just formatted what was already there, nothing else changed?

Comment: @AlexPoole what I understood is, that he wants only the "John"s that have last name in the format of "*ohn".  The way his question was originally formatted it didn't look like he's looking for "Sam"s and "Jack"s as well. But better let Curious explain - maybe it was I who didn't understand what he meant.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell quite what you want here - do mean that for any first names that appear more than once, you want to show both the first and last names of all matching records? If so you can use an analytic function, something like:

```
select first_name, last_name
from (
    select first_name, last_name,
        count() over (partition by first_name) as cnt
)
where cnt > 1;
```

The inner query adds a virtual column to each row that shows how many times the first name appears in the whole data set; the outer query then filters out any that only appear once. This is better than a self-join, in general, as you only hit the table once.

If you are only interested in specific last names too, you can add a filter for those (as per DCookie's answer) in either level, with slightly different results - depends if you want all surnames included in the count, or only the specific ones in your list.

---

Of course, if this is homework and you've just been learning about self joins, that may be the way you should go for now - although I'm not a fan of teaching something sub-optimal, unless it's to show you why that's the case. If it is homework, see how far you can get and then add your attempt and any errors etc. to the question.

Comment: A better answer than mine ;-)